# Why is it that this "toggle" code only works in order?

Tags: javascript

Imagine a page of images in a single column. This "image zoom" effect switcher only works in forward order. For some reason, I can't toggle any image elements backwards.

Examples:

1. click on image 1, then image 2 (code will zoom image 1, then zoom image 2, closing image 1)
2. click on image 2, then image 1 (code will zoom image 2, then nothing)

```
// install image zoom effect
window.onload = function () {
  addEventToFigureImg()
};

function addEventToFigureImg() {
  var htmlFigures = document.getElementsByTagName("figure");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < htmlFigures.length; i++) {
    htmlFigures[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var effectCount = document.getElementsByClassName("effect-zoom");

      //switch on
      this.classList.toggle("effect-zoom");
      document.documentElement.classList.add("not-a-modal-background");
      
      // zoom others out if there are more than 1 
      if (effectCount.length >= 2) {
          effectCount[0].classList.remove("effect-zoom");
      };
      
      // switch off if there are no zoom effects
      if (effectCount.length <= 0) {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("not-a-modal-background");
      };
      
    }, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: _"zoom others out if there are more than 1"_ - You only remove the class from the first element in `effectCount`. When you click on "image 1", `effectCount[0]` will be "image 1".

Comment: Is there a better way to identify the "other" elements on the page? I'm trying a for loop right now but it feels inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after breaking down the logic some more. Thanks for the hints!

```
  function addEventToFigureImg() {
  var htmlFigures = document.getElementsByTagName("figure");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < htmlFigures.length; i++) {
    htmlFigures[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      
      // toggle zoom and add darkroom effect
      this.classList.toggle("effect-zoom");
      document.documentElement.classList.add("not-a-modal-background");
      
      // center this
      this.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center"
      });
      
      // count zoom effect
      var effectCount = document.getElementsByClassName("effect-zoom");

      // if there are no zoom effects
      if (effectCount.length <= 0) {
        // remove darkroom 
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("not-a-modal-background");
      }

      // if there are more effects
      else if (effectCount.length >= 1) {
        // find all effects
        for (var i = 0; i < htmlFigures.length; i++) {
          // zoom out others
          htmlFigures[i].classList.remove("effect-zoom");
        }
        this.classList.toggle("effect-zoom");
      };
      
    }, false);
  }
}
```